# Visual Studio 2013 - Debugging Ajax, where are the error messages in Internet Explorer Debugging tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I had a problem with some of my Javascript / Ajax code basically I made a typo in an Ajax call. Something like the following - loadtext.html was incorrectly named lodtext.html (This is a simplified example)

```
            $("#loadButton").click(function () {
            $("#loadDiv").load("lodtext.html");
```

There was no error message or anything that pointed me to this problem. Looking in the Internet Explorer debugging tools i would have expected to see something like

"lodtext.html does not exist"

or similar. Is there someway of finding problems like this using the debugging tools. (or should I switch to another browser?) I would have expected this problem to be displayed in an obvious way

Comment: please check your path is correct for loatext.html

Comment: That is not the question. I have fixed the problem.
I want to know how to debugger a similar problem in the future using the debugging tools

Comment: Sorry, I take your question wrong. Yes you can check in debugging tools in console tab.If your path not found, you will get 404 File not found error. you can correct your by this.

Comment: That is the problem I have. If I open the debugger tools go to the console window and press the button, nothing happens and no errors are written to the console window in the debugging tools. Is there another step I need to take?

Comment: I have tried it in Chrome and I do get a 404 error! I could switch to that

Comment: Yes, chrome and mozilla is better for debugging facility and easier to understand. we usually use chrome or firebug on mozilla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83502/discussion-between-arvaan-and-nick-le-page).

Comment: For IE 11: Press F12 and click on the tap "Network"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switch to using the debug tools in Chrome. The debug window displayed the 404 error which IE tools was not displaying for some reason